# Printing nested dictionaries in nice readable fashion

Tags: python, dictionary

Im looking to print a nested dictionary in a nice clean readable format. I have done the standard approach of printing dictionary keys and their values but as this is nested it doesnt present very well. Could someone explain how I could achieve the below formatting?

```
Host             Port    Service
192.168.1.200     80     IIS 7.5
                  443    IIS 7.5

192.168.1.201     22     SSHv.199
```

Dictionary Example

```
192.168.1.200 {'3389': 'Microsoft Terminal Service', '49160': 'Microsoft Windows RPC', '49163': 'Microsoft Windows RPC', '135': 'Microsoft Windows RPC', '49152': 'Microsoft Windows RPC', '49153': 'Microsoft Windows RPC'}
```

Comment: If it's a nested dictionary, try a nested loop.

Comment: Your dictionary example also doesn't seem to have a correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formatting options with `json.dumps`:

```
>>> d={'server1':{'3389': 'Microsoft Terminal Service', '49160': 'Microsoft Windows RPC', '49163': 'Microsoft Windows RPC', '135': 'Microsoft Windows RPC', '49152': 'Microsoft Windows RPC', '49153':'Microsoft Windows RPC'},'server2':{'morekeys':'morevalues'}}
>>> print json.dumps(d, indent=4)
{
    "server1": {
        "3389": "Microsoft Terminal Service", 
        "49160": "Microsoft Windows RPC", 
        "49163": "Microsoft Windows RPC", 
        "135": "Microsoft Windows RPC", 
        "49152": "Microsoft Windows RPC", 
        "49153": "Microsoft Windows RPC"
    }, 
    "server2": {
        "morekeys": "morevalues"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I don't know why I suggested pprint, that was silly. This is THE solution.

Comment: Haha, well I started down that road but liked this more :) much simpler

Comment: Absolutely. Funny thing, I took the OP sample to jsonlint.com first to look at it, yet still tried using pprint. :)

Comment: rofl at how simple that was. ive been sat here playing with various nested loops and havent come close to that output style. thanks rofls. Is there a way to pritty it up abit?

Comment: looking at the docs, there isnt with json.dumps, well least not in the formatting i want sad times. Back to the nested loops?

Comment: Well, json.dumps returns a string, so instead of just printing it you can do things like: `json.dumps(d, indent=4).replace(':','\t')` to replace all of the occurences of `:` with a tab. It will still take a bit of work to get to your desired output though.